# Java | Generate Xml from Xsd and Variables

Tags: java, xml, xsd

In Java i like to generate a XML-String. As input there exists an XSD-file and corresponding variables. How to accomplish this?

It would be nice to validate the resulting XML backwards against the XSD (e.g if some variables are missing or containing invalid values).

Is there a way to do this with XMlBeans/Xalan/Xerces?

Answer (score 0):

I know XMLSpy can generate a sample XML file from XSD/DTD, but it's not free